# How to stream multiple videos from one source?

Tags: video, streaming

Are there any way to stream multiple videos from one source?

Currently I use VLC to stream one video file across LAN network.
I wanted to add multiple playlist of videos and stream them one after another.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scheduled broadcasting:

> http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch05.html#id351447

```
new my_media broadcast enabled
setup my_media input my_video.mpeg input my_other_movie.mpeg
setup my_media output #rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.1.1,port=5004,sdp=sap://,name="My Media"}

new my_sched schedule enabled
setup my_sched date 2012/12/12-12:12:12
setup my_sched append control my_media play
```